# Server Side Includes not working

Tags: html, ssi, shtml

I am attempting to use SSI to call my footer into my website but it isnt working. I am not sure if I have to include a command telling the server that it is SSI?

FOOTER FILE:

footer.shtml

```
<footer id="footer">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <p class="source"><i>“Unless someone like you cares a whole awful lot,
                        Nothing is going to get better. It's not.” ― Dr. Seuss, The Lorax</i></p>

                </div>
                <div class="source">
                    <p>&copy; 2016 Climate Change. All Rights Reserved. </p>
                    <p>Terms of Use | Privacy Policy </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

CALLING THE FILE:

```
<!--#include file="../climate-change/assets/resources/footer.shtml"-->
```

Comment: How you (or if you can) configure a server to process SSI directives depends on the server you are using.

Comment: ah so the issue is my server and not my code?

Comment: Some resources: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/webmaster/article.php/3473341/SSI-The-Include-Command.htm

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/ssi.html

Comment: Michael, I based my code off of the understanding of your second link that you posted. It seems that my code is correct and that it is my server that is the issue. As I do not have direct control of the server that I am using Ill have to turn to the admin for support. Thank you.